# Changes inside media query in sass project not reflecting in any browser. Could this be a problem with Parcel bundler?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, parceljs

I am learning sass and I am stuck at this. I have added a media query to the &__right class in the _grid.scss file using @include. I have defined the sass map and @mixin in the _breakpoints.scss file. I have used @use and correct namespace (ut) in the _grid.scss file to properly link everything.

The npm scripts are correctly defined in package.json. I use npm start and npm run build-dev to start and build the project. The viewport meta tag is also present in my html file. Then I added the media query **ut.breakpoint-down(medium)** inside the &__right class. The styles I applied to this media query **ut.breakpoint-down(medium)** for the "medium" device (or any device defined in the **$breakpoints-down map**) aren't reflected in the browser. The text color, background color, text alignment are not working at this breakpoint. They aren't working in any browser (I tried chrome, firefox, brave). The code inside this media query is not visible in dev tools either when I select the div with class &__right .. I can see the code only when I open the _grid.scss file inside dev tools.

I have tried clearing browser cache. It still doesn't work. I am using Parceljs bundler. (I have installed all dev dependencies as well). I can't figure out what is wrong. This is the _grid.scss file.

```
@use '../util/' as ut;

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: min(100% - 40px, 1000px);
  margin-inline: auto;

  @include ut.breakpoint-up(large) {
      grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto;
}

&__left, &__right {
    padding: 2rem;
}

&__left {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

&__right {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    
    @include ut.breakpoint-down(medium) {
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
        background-color: red;
    }

   }
  }
```

Here is the code in the _breakpoints.scss file where I have defined the media query in the @mixin **breakpoint-down($size)**:

```
$breakpoints-up: (
"medium": 43.75em,
"large": 56.25em,
"xlarge": 90em,
);

$breakpoints-down: (
"small": 43.74875em,
"medium": 56.24875,
"large": 89.99875,
);

@mixin breakpoint-up($size) {
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints-up,$size)) {
    @content;
 }
}


@mixin breakpoint-down($size) {
   @media (max-width: map-get($breakpoints-down,$size)) {
     @content;
 }
}
```

Could this be a problem with Parcel bundler or is there something else I am missing about how to use the media query inside the &__right class?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to this. It does seem like there is a very minor Parceljs issue at play here. This is what I had to do to fix it:

Turns out the live server bundled with parcel (localhost:1234) **does not reflect changes in browser in case of nested media queries defined in a mixin**. To see the changes applied inside the **ut.breakpoint-down(medium)** mixin I had to:

1. npm run build-dev
2. npm start
3. Close all previously opened localhost browser windows (this is what I hadn't figured out earlier)

This means each time I have to view the applied changes I must

1. Build the project
2. Start localhost
3. Close previously opened localhost browser windows

This means that the live server functionality bundled with parceljs does not work when changes are applied to **nested media queries defined in a mixin**. Otherwise the live server bundled with parceljs works absolutely fine and updates changes instantly (as it is supposed to) for everything outside the **nested media query defined in a mixin**.

This seems like an incredibly minor issue but it had me struggling for a couple of days. If someone else comes across this issue, I hope this helps.